# Login doesn't intercept calls with hashtag using spring security and angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I configured spring security to catch all the requests. The problem is that when an url has a hashtag symbol, the login doesn't appears.

If I enter /dashboard, the login appears. But if I enter to /localhost/#/dash.board it won't

This is my configuration for spring security

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/impersonate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/switch").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");

}
```

I'm looking all my code, but I'm not sure of the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And it never will. A `#` is an anchor which is processed on the client and isn't send to the server. So everything after the `#` will not reach the server. This is all specified in the http spec.

Comment: I know that. But spring security must intercept that kind of urls, right? Cause they don't match with any permit all config that I have

Comment: No because they are never submitted to the server, there is nothing to intercept.

Comment: So, is there a way to work with angularjs views and spring security?

Comment: Only for the calls that goto the server on the client you will have to do things yourself.